# How could bandwidth be throttled/limited programmatically in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, throttling, bandwidth-throttling

In OS X 10.10 ipfw (ipfirewall) was removed and replaced with pf firewall. pf uses the ALTQ network scheduler which can be used create bandwidth rules. ALTQ is not supported in the 10.10 kernel so any bandwidth rules are ignored. Several UI tools such as Icefloor currently do not support bandwidth management in Yosemite as a result.

As far as I am aware only Apples' Network Link Conditioner is able to manipulate bandwidth but unfortunately this is just a Preference Pane - I've no idea how they achieve it.

Are there any other tools out there that can be used? Can this be done at a lower level?

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: The answer to this question is dummynet. The CLI tool we've been looking for is `dnctl`. Read the man page with `man dnctl`. We can create pipes and queues and then use PF to direct the desired traffic through them. It's all documented in that dnctl man page. Hooray, NLC is not needed.

---

To understand how Apple is achieving the desired affect, take a look at your PF rules before and after enabling NLC. Notice that when NLC is enabled, you have a dummynet PF rule?! That's right, instead of supporting ALTQ, it appears that Apple is using PF with dummynet. I posted [a bit more about it on my blog](http://matt.simerson.net/news/2015/03/09/bandwidth-shaping-on-mac-os-x).

There's no documentation for how to manipulate dummynet without the ipfw tool, and there's not yet anything in the `pf.conf` or `dummynet` man pages. So cheat like I did, and copy the ipfw binary over from an older Mac OS X install.